# Segfault when NOT using printf

Tags: c, linux, for-loop, segmentation-fault, printf

I am using POSIX threads, and at the end of my program, I am waiting to join each of the threads.  After some time of running perfectly well, my code started returning a weird bug when I was waiting for the threads.

```
pthreads threads[C+P];

for(i = 0; i < (C+P); i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);  
    pthread_join(threads[i]);
}
```

If I remove the printf statement, or replace it with any other printf statement, a delay, or any other operation on i, I still get a segfault.

How would I start debugging this?

Comment: I'd start with getting a stack trace when the program segfaults, using `gdb`.

Comment: knowing where threads[] is, what it contains (I'm assuming pthread_t values), where i is on the stack relative to it (odd thing to ask I know, but so is your question) and how C+P relates to the magnitude of threads[] will probably help. As it stands now, the only way this could privy less information would be if you left out the for-loop from the snippet. We don't know if threads[] is a dynamic array (`pthread_t *threads;`), a fixed array (`pthread_t threads[N];`), etc. Can you give us a bigger bone to chew on?

Comment: At a guess, you have some sort of race condition elsewhere in your code. `printf()`, being console I/O that flushes on every call, is slow, and masks this condition.

Comment: millimoose: If this were the case, I would expect that a delay would solve the problem as well.

WhozCraig: I really don't know what else to give you beyond the most recent edit.  I'm trying to figure out how to use gdb to solve this, but I'm not proficient with it.

Comment: **edit** replacing with fflush had the same effect. You were correct, and I identified a race condition elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inserting `printf()` call affects memory layout (and thus it can, by pure accident, mask some memory corruption), as well as execution timing (you use threads, so timing is also relevant).

But instead of any sort of guesswork, you should do some regular debugging:

- run you executable under [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), this way you should be able to see what exact operation is causing a crash, where is it called from, etc.
- run it under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) - this tool detects a lot of common errors, like accessing free'd memory block, using uninitialized variables, exceeding array/buffer boundaries, etc. It's not uncommon to immediately get exact position of the error with `valgrind`, I highly recommend it!

Comment: This is not an answer; should be a comment